# Debugging Angular HttpClient observables: where can I set a breakpoint to see what's returned from the server?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, observable

I'm new to Angular and "reactive programming".

I have an Angular 8 component (test-api.component.*) that uses a service (contacts.service.ts) to talk to a REST back-end.  It looks like this:

**test-api.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Contact } from '../models/contact';
import { ContactsService } from '../services/contacts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-api',
  templateUrl: './test-api.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-api.component.css']
})
export class TestAPIComponent implements OnInit {

  // "$" convention denotes this as an "Observable"
  contacts$: Observable<Contact[]>;

  constructor(private contactsService: ContactsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadContacts();
  }

  loadContacts() {
    this.contacts$ = this.contactsService.getContacts();
  }
}
```

**test-api-component.html**:

```
<h1>Contacts</h1>
<p *ngIf="!(contacts$ | async)"><em>Loading...</em></p>
<table class="table table-sm table-hover" *ngIf="(contacts$ | async)?.length > 0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ContactId</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>EMail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let contact of (contacts$ | async)">
      <td>{{ contact.ContactId }}</td>
      <td>{{ contact.Name }}</td>
      <td>{{ contact.EMail }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm developing with Visual Studio code.

Q: How/where can I set a breakpoint in my code so I can see my `contacts[]` array in the debugger after the async operation has completed???  I just want to be able to look at individual "contact" elements in the debugger.

A simple question - but any help/advice would definitely be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

---

Thank you all: Mustafa Kunwa, Himanshu Singh and Andrei Gătej.

I know how to set breakpoints and use JS debuggers (both VSCode/Chrome extensions and Chrome Developer Tools), but I *didn't* know how best to modify the code so that I could *examine* the data that was otherwise going straight into the HTML template.

Andrei Gătej gave the most detailed answer to my implicit questions (what exactly is happening "under the covers" when I declare an "Observable" or pipe "async"?)

Both Mustafa Kunwa and Himanshu Singh gave me effectively the *SAME* answer - the one that I went with.  So it was hard to decide which to "accept".

Anyway, my final code looks like this:

**test-api.component.html**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let contact of (contactsList)">
      <td>{{ contact.contactId }}</td>
      <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ contact.eMail }}</td>
 ...
```

**test-api.component.ts**

```
export class TestAPIComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  contactsList: Contact[];
  private contactsSubscription$: Subscription;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactsSubscription$ =
      this.contactsService.getContacts().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.contactsList = data;
          console.log('loadContacts', data);
        },
        err => {
          console.error('loadContacts', err);
        });
  ...
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.contactsSubscription$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: 1. Open the developer console in chrome 2. Open the respective file and set the breakpoint **OR** 1. Type in `debugger` above the line you want to debug 2. Open the developer console in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 this.contactsService.getContacts().subscribe(
     res=>{
      console.log(res);
     },
     err=>{
       console.log(err);
     });
```

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm - it sounds like Mustafa Kunwa and Himanshu Singh are giving me exactly what I'm looking for: the ability to set a breakpoint at a point *AFTER* the async operation has completed.  Q: What's wrong with the above?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `loadContacts()` from ngOnInit(). You can directly fetch data from API in `ngOnInit()` only. Then on the mentioned line in code you can add `debug` point to see the data received from the API

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.contactsService.getContacts().subscribe((data)=>{
       console.log(data);       // <---- here you can add debug point
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your template you are applying the **async pipe** **twice** to your observable, which will create 2 subscribers.

Although the **async pipe** takes care of **unsubscribing** from your **observable**, having multiple subscriptions might be redundant.

To solve this, you can wrap your part of the template which will make use of that observable(`contacts$`) with an `ng-container`, so that only one subscription will be created

#### test.component.html

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(contacts$ | async) as contacts; else loading">
    <h1>Contacts</h1>

    <table class="table table-sm table-hover" *ngIf="contacts.length > 0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ContactId</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>EMail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let contact of (contacts$ | async)">
            <td>{{ contact.ContactId }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.EMail }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p *ngIf="contacts.length === 0">No contacts!</p>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
    <p>
        <em>Loading...</em>
    </p>
</ng-template>
```

---

Regarding your question, I find Nicholas' first comment helpful.

Besides the debugger, here is my preferred approach:

```js
loadContacts() {
 this.contacts$ = this.contactsService.getContacts().pipe(tap(console.log));
}
```

Comment: Your reply helps - thank you. If this were a nice FORTRAN or BASIC program, I'd just "block" until the data was ready.  If this were a plan JS program, I'd read the asynchronous data in a callback.  But here, 1) I want *one* "subscription", 2) and even though I want to display the data (in the .html), 3) I also want to SEE the data in my debugger.  I *DON'T* want multiple subscriptions, I *DON'T* want to rely only on what's displayed in HTML.  Your reply brings me closer - thank you :)

Comment: Glad it helped! The soonest moment when you could see the incoming data would be inside an interceptor, by doing: `next.handle(req).pipe(filter(e => e instanceof HttpResponse), tap(console.log))`.

Comment: Or, alternatively, 1) forget about  "`contacts$: Observable<Contact[]>;`" 2) Substitute "`contactsList: Contact[]`" instead, 3) call "`subscribe()`" in the component.  Correct?

Comment: It may work, but it may as well become harder to maintain in the long term this way. I'd suggest passing, if possible,the `contracts` data as `@Input` params  without having to manually manage the subscriptions: `<test [contracts]="contracts$ | async"></test>`. This way, you can also leverage the **smart** and **dumb** components strategy.